# File that sits in Static Folder of Nuxt JS Application is not displaying in iframe once deployed to AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, nuxt.js, aws-amplify, static-site

I need to display an html file in an iframe. The html file is sitting in the static folder of my Nuxt Application. When running npm run dev and npm run start, I can see the content of the iframe perfectly. When I deploy the project to my staging environment on AWS Amplify I get an error saying 'Page not found'. There are no errors in my console.

[image]

The folder structure in the static folder is

```
static
--modules
  --module
    --folder
    --folder
    --folder
    --story.html <-- this is the file needing to display in the iframe.
```

I'm using Nuxt JS version 2.15.8.

My nuxt.config file looks like this:

```
export default {

 target: 'static',
  // Disable server-side rendering: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode
  ssr: false,

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'digital-spaces',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap'
      }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/hygraph.js',
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/style-resources',
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
    '@nuxt/image',
  ],

  styleResources: {
    scss: [
      '~/assets/styles/variables.scss',
      '~/assets/styles/globals.scss',
      '~/assets/styles/mixins.scss',
    ],
  },

  image: {
    domains: ['https://media.graphassets.com']
  },

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/i18n',
  ],

  generate: {
    subFolders: true
  }, 
  
  router: {
    base: '/'
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
  }
}
```

My amplify.yml file in the Build settings of AWS Amplify is:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run generate
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

If anyone can let me know if I'm missing something, that would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Which Iframe URL using ? because to get data from Iframe need to have cross domain policy enabled. is this code is working fine in local machine ?

Comment: Yes the code works on local. How would I enable cross domain policy?

Comment: you have any link to where can check what is issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is password protected and I can't share those details. I reference the file in the iframe like this 
`<iframe :src="'/modules/'+thisSlug+'/story.html'" ></iframe>`

When I go to the network tab to find the file it's there but just shows the nuxt error html inside it. It exists on my branch in bitbucket that the hosting provider is linked to.